# SharePoint Server 2013 Search Host Controller error 1067

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I can not start SharePoint Search Host Controller,

I added the domain account in local administrator group and I restarted the server

but still I can not start this service

some of the fox told to run blow command but still it is not working

```
$SA = Get-SPServiceInstance | Where {$_.Status -like “Provisioning”}

$SA.Unprovision()

$SA.Provision()
```

can anyone tell me how can I start this services why it is shut down unexpectedly

Comment: check this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a67b0d0f-4f5a-4412-8f83-a57eaff4be45/sharepoint-search-host-controller-does-not-start?forum=sharepointsearch